# laravel tabla pivot

Tags: laravel-5

buenas estoy tratando de resolver una relación de muchos a muchos con una tabla pivot todo funciona bien excepto cuando deseo obtener los datos de la tabla 4 que esta asociada a la tabla 3. les muestro

```html
la tabla 1 
- id
- nombre
- descripción


la tabla 3
- id
- categoría
- descripción


la tabla 2 es una tabla pivot que se llama tabla1_tabla3
-id
-tabla1_id
-tabla3_id


la tabla 4
-id
-tabla3_id
-indicaciones
```

la tabla 4 es una tabla que hace referencia a la tabla 3 ya que son indicaciones de esas categorías.

todo bien hasta ahí, entonces los modelos

```html
tabla 1
    public function tabla3()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(tabla3::class)->withPivot('id');
    }

tabla 3
    public function tabla1()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(tabla1::class)->withPivot('id');
    }
    public function tabla4()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(tabla1::class);
    }

tabla 4
    public function tabla3()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(tabla3::class);
    }
```

esos son los modelos todos funcionan bien puedo guardar las relaciones de las tabla 1 y 3 en la tabla 2 que es la pivot.

el problema es que el controlador que estoy implementando para la tabla 1 es el siguiente Tabla1Tabla4Controller.php el cual debe acceder por medio de la tabla 1 a la tabla 4 de una relación especifica  de la tabla pivot.

en el metodo index es el siguiente

```html
public function index(Tabla1 $tabla1, Tabla3 $tabla3)
{
  $tabla4= $tabla1->tabla3()->withPivot('tabla3_id')->$tabla3->tabla4;
  return $this->showAll($tabla4);
} 

el error es el siguiente 

"Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::${"id":3,"categoria":"Brayan Haag","descripcion":"Modi","created_at":"2019-07-08 18:09:09","updated_at":"2019-07-08 18:09:09","deleted_at":null}"
```

lo cual quiere decir que esta accediendo a los datos de la tabla 1 y por medico del id de uno de los datos de la tabla 1 en este caso el id 2 que es un producto  accede a la tabla pivot que es una relacion entre ese producto y la categoria con id 3 y por medico de esa categoria id 3 deseo ver sus indicaciones que es la tabla 4, pero solo logro acceder hasta los datos de esa categoria como pueden ver el error posiblemente esta en como se deba acceder por la funcion index

$tabla4= $tabla1->tabla3()->withPivot('tabla3_id')->$tabla3->tabla4;

estoy usando postman para generar las cunsultas a la api restfull por el metodo get por medio de la url apirestful.test/api/tablas1/2/relacion/3/tablas4

como pueden ver el error no logro descifrarlo soy nuevo en laravel y necesito de la ayuda de ustedes le agradezco su respuesta.